# Facebook component for Xamarin: app domain?

Tags: android, facebook, xaml, xamarin, components

I hope you can help me.
I'm using the sample of Facebook SDK https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk but I'm having some issues. 
When I lunch the application test from Xamarin and try to do the login I have this error:
"Can't load url: the domain of this url isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this url, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings. "

I haven't any domain App ....

Comment: Did you create a facebook developer account to fill in the FacebookAppId?

Comment: yes, I did, If appid is missing the page give me another error, so it isn't the problem.